# Add a variable to input beside a checkbox (onchange event) where there the table is shown from a "while"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

The user has to choose a date first, I get the value from this input.
The part below that is a list from mysql that looks like this: Name / Checkbox / date input" where upon clicking/changing the checkbox for any of the Names, the "date input" will change into the same date from the first part so that it can be later saved into the db.

```js
$('.boton').change(function() {
  var fechai1 = $('#fechai').val();
  var fechaf1 = $('#fechaf').val();
  var horai = $('#horai').val();
  var horaf = $('#horaf').val();
  $('#fechai-cambio').val(fechai1);
  $('#fechaf-cambio').val(fechaf1);
  $('#horai-cambio').val(horai);
  $('#horaf-cambio').val(horaf);

  var fechai = new Date(fechai1);
  var month = fechai.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var day = fechai.getUTCDate();
  var year = fechai.getUTCFullYear();
  var newdate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

  var fechaf = new Date(fechaf1);
  var month1 = fechaf.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  var day1 = fechaf.getUTCDate();
  var year1 = fechaf.getUTCFullYear();
  var newdate1 = year1 + "-" + month1 + "-" + day1;

  var fechaI = new Date(newdate)
  var fechaF = new Date(newdate1)

  var difM = fechaF - fechaI // diferencia en milisegundos
  var difD = difM / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) // diferencia en dias

  console.log(difD)

  $('#dias').val(difD);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='cantp'>Cantidad de Personas</label > 
            <input type='text' id='cantp' name='cantp' readonly value=''>
        <label for='razon' >Fecha Inicio</label>
<input type='date' id='fechai' name='fechai' class='fechai'>
<label for='fechaf'>Fecha Fin</label>
<input type='date' id='fechaf' name='fechaf'>
<label for='horai'>Hora inicio</label>
<input type='time' id='horai' name='horai'>
<label for='horaf'>Hora Fin</label>
<input type='time' id='horaf' name='horaf'>
<br>

<tr>
  <td>elimar carrasquero</td>
  <td class="text-center"><input class="boton" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1"></td>
  <td><input type="date" id="fechai-cambio" name="fechai-cambio" class="fecicamb"></td>
  <td><input type="date" id="fechaf-cambio" name="fechaf-cambio" class="fecfcamb"></td>
  <td><input type="time" id="horai-cambio" name="horai-cambio"></td>
  <td><input type="time" id="horaf-cambio" name="horaf-cambio"></td>
  <td><input style="width:20px;" readonly id="dias"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>carla romero</td>
  <td class="text-center"><input class="boton" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2"></td>
  <td><input type="date" id="fechai-cambio" name="fechai-cambio" class="fecicamb"></td>
  <td><input type="date" id="fechaf-cambio" name="fechaf-cambio" class="fecfcamb"></td>
  <td><input type="time" id="horai-cambio" name="horai-cambio"></td>
  <td><input type="time" id="horaf-cambio" name="horaf-cambio"></td>
  <td><input style="width:20px;" readonly id="dias"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>jesus acosta</td>
  <td class="text-center"><input class="boton" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3"></td>
  <td><input type="date" id="fechai-cambio" name="fechai-cambio" class="fecicamb"></td>
  <td><input type="date" id="fechaf-cambio" name="fechaf-cambio" class="fecfcamb"></td>
  <td><input type="time" id="horai-cambio" name="horai-cambio"></td>
  <td><input type="time" id="horaf-cambio" name="horaf-cambio"></td>
  <td><input style="width:20px;" readonly id="dias"></td>
</tr><button id='btn_form' type='button' onclick='realizaGrupo()'>Grabar</button> </form>
</article>
```

Comment: This does not look like a PHP/MYSQL issue. Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55456515/edit) then the `[<>]` snippet editor and post RENDERED HTML without PHP if you want to have a jQuery solution.

Comment: tried to add the edit, x.x

Comment: Where is the HTML? I did not mean add the sentence I wrote, I mean right-click your page and copy enough RELEVANT html from view-source

Comment: I tried to help you with HTML but your HTML is invalid - your table is not valid HTML. You have multiple IDs that are the same.

Comment: Please fix your code, then use class instead of ID since you can only have ONE of each ID - You have nothing called `horai-cambio`

Comment: i added the html srry

Comment: The HTML is not valid. Not complete and you cannot have duplicate IDs. Please fix your HTML and use a class instead of an ID. You can use `var $ row = $(this).closest("tr")` to get the row of an object and then do `$row.find(".someotherelementsclass").val(this.value)` to set the value

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you on the right track

```js
// Identify HTML elements
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const dateSource = document.querySelector("#dateSource");

// Listen for clicks inside parent container
container.addEventListener("click", pasteDate);

// Update the date in the same row when the checkbox is clicked
function pasteDate(event){
  if(event.target.checked){
    event.target.nextSibling.value = dateSource.value;
  }
  else{
    event.target.nextSibling.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="dateSource" type="date" value="2019-04-01" />
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><input type="date" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><input type="date" />
  </div>
</div>
```